# add elements in array dynamically using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am new to XSLT and I am trying to declare array and add elements in array based on some conditions and then check if array has any elements or not.

**Input xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
<data>
        <name>rocky</name>
        <sal>1</sal>
</data>
</Employees>
```

**xslt:-**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Employee">
    <xsl:variable name="empname" select="./data/name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sal" select="./data/sal"/>
    <xsl:variable name='errorList'/> -- here i am not sure, how to  declare the array and is this errorList accessible in another template i have created. if not then i am planning to declare that outside both the templates
        <Details>
            <EmployeeName>
              <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="not($empname=('rocky'))"/>
                   //here i have to populate errorlist with 'name is invalid'
              </xsl:choose>

              <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="not($sal=('10'))"/>
                   //here i have to populate errorlist with 'salary is invalid greater than 1'
              </xsl:choose>
               //here i have to check if errorlist is not empty, then if this condition is satisfied then appy the below template
               <xsl:apply-templates select="/Employee/data/name"/>
             </EmployeeName>
        </Details>
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="/Employee/data/name">
 here i will apply for loop on errorList
<xsl:for-each select="errorList">
<ErrorList>
  <Error>
 </Error>
</ErrorList>
</xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required output is which i want dynamicall, i can use any other feature by xslt which stores the errors and display at once:-**

```
 <ErrorList>
<Error>'name is invalid'</Error>
<Error>'salary is invalid greater than 1'</Error>
</ErrorList>
```

Comment: Can you explain what your required output is? In XSLT you don't "declare arrays".

Comment: I have updated my required output, kindly let me know how this can be achieved @Sebastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: **EDITED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Employee">
    <xsl:variable name="empname" select="./data/name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sal" select="./data/sal"/>

    <xsl:variable name='errorList' as="element()*">
      <xsl:if test="not($empname=('rocky'))">
        <error type="nameIsInvalid"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not($sal=('10'))">
        <error type="salaryIsInvalid"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <Details>
      <EmployeeName>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count($errorList) gt 0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$errorList"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data/name"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </EmployeeName>
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/Employee/data/name">
    <!-- Do something with the name -->
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="error">
    <!-- Do something with the error -->
    <!-- i.e. just copy the error-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you mean when we are applying template with xsl:apply-templates select="$errorList"/> then control goes to  in error template? if that is the case then how can i access errorList ? or nameIsInvalid and salaryIsInvalid in error template

Comment: Yes, by  <xsl:apply-templates select="$errorList"/> each error in the errorList wil be matched in the <xsl:template match="error">. I don't understand your question: "how can i access errorList?". What do you want?

Comment: I am trying something like  to show both 2 errors in the response please let me know what exactly i am missing here..<xsl:template match="error">
  <xsl:for-each select="errorList">
  <error>
  <xsl:value-of select="$error"/>
  </error>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: see an example in the template

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here's something to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ErrorList>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Employees/data"/>
    </ErrorList>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <EmployeeName>
      <xsl:if test="not(name='rocky')">
        <Error>Name is invalid</Error>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not(sal='10')">
        <Error>Salary is invalid, greater than 1</Error>
      </xsl:if>
    </EmployeeName>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA11